# Is there any connection between Indiana Jones's whip and his fear of snakes?

Tags: indiana-jones

Indiana Jones is famous for using a whip as his primary weapon and tool of choice for most situations. Equally well known about him, and a major part of his character, is his fear of snakes.

Given all of the items Indy could have been written with, a whip seems to be the most snake-like of all of them. **Is there any intentional connection between these two parts of his character?** Or am I just looking for connections where there is none?

Comment: If we go in-universe, the whip *and* the snake-fear are explained in the prologue to *Last Crusade* and are not really related. Interesting question, though.

Comment: Freud would undoubtedly have an answer for this question.

Comment: I suspect you're looking for connections where there aren't any, and that the whip was chosen because they thought it would be cool.

Comment: How does he feel about cucumbers? What about garden hoses? Going into his sock drawer must be terrifying!

Comment: @DJClayworth Sometimes a whip is just a whip ....

Answer (score 4):

The prologue to Last Crusade heavily suggests that he acquired his whip AND his fear of snakes during the train sequence but in separate events. First, he falls into that snake-pit-box thing and then he gets the whip when he falls into the lion car. He's never shown on-screen surrendering the whip once he's pulled out, only the Cross of Coronado. 
All that said, I don't recall seeing him with the whip after he's pulled out of the lion car, when he goes into the caboose, or when he's running back to his house. I'd have to watch the sequence again but it's certainly implied that's the whip he winds up with during his later adventures.